# Bytes to megabytes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In javascript (or coffeescript), I have the following function:

```
bytesToMegabytes = (bytes) ->
  return Math.round((b/1024/1024) * 100) / 100
```

I'm trying to recreate it in ruby. I have:

```
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    (((bytes.to_i/1024/1024) * 100) / 100).round
end
```

But this rounds differently? For example, 1153597 becomes 1 in the ruby code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is it rounding differently?

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but I know that `to_i` makes something an integer. Perhaps you're doing that too early? In most languages, integer division will have an integer result, so if that's true in Ruby, you may want to defer that `to_i` until later in the calculation.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Rails defines [`Numeric#megabyte`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-megabyte), so you can write `bytes / 1.megabyte` or `(bytes / 1.0.megabyte).round`

Answer (score 13):

I don't want to be a smart-ass, but no one seems to notice the calculation confusion here. 1 megabyte is simply 1000000 byte ([google it](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=megabyte%20to%20byte)). The 1024 is an outdated confusion about 10^2 byte which is 1024 kilobyte. Since 1998 this has become known as a kibibyte ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)) and is now the norm.

That means you should just divide your byte by 1000000 and you're done. I've added some rounding for extra usefulness:

```
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    (bytes.to_f / 1000000).round(2)
end
puts bytes_to_megabytes(1153597)  # outputs 1.15
```

Comment: Actual answer right here. This outputs the correct number based on what my operating system shows the size of the file.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    bytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0) 
end
bytes_to_megabytes(1153597)
#=> 1.1001558303833008
```

You can make `CONSTANT` variable like

```
MEGABYTES = 1024.0 * 1024.0
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    bytes / MEGABYTES
end
bytes_to_megabytes(1153597)
#=> 1.1001558303833008
```

Now make you clear about `to_i` and `round`,

> But this rounds differently? For example, 1153597 becomes 1 in the
>   ruby code.

**to_i** method take only decimal part it does not roundup the number for that you have to convert to `float` then roundup

```
 > "148.68".to_i
 #=> 148 
 > "148.68".to_f.round
 #=> 149
```

As [*Stefen's comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772368/bytes-to-megabytes-in-ruby#comment-49598573) : In Rails You can do simply like this:

```
 > 1153597 / 1.0.megabyte
 #=> 1.1001558303833008 
 > (1153597 / 1.0.megabyte).round
 #=> 1
```

For more details of `megabyte` method **[Numeric#megabyte](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-megabyte)**

Comment: In Rails, that constant is `Numeric::MEGABYTE`

Comment: If you have have rails gems installed, you can just do `require 'active_support/core_ext'` to do `1.0.megabyte` without rails.

Answer (score 5):

```
1153597/1024
=> 1126
1153597/1024/1024
=> 1
```

This makes sense, since with integer division you get an integer result and 1153597 Bytes is roughly equal to 1MB. If you convert your input to a float first, it may be what you expect:

```
1153597.0/1024/1024
=> 1.1001558303833008
```

Therefore, change the code to use `to_f` instead of `to_i`, and remove `round`

```
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    (((bytes.to_f/1024/1024) * 100) / 100)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

With Ruby on Rails:

```
def bytes_to_megabytes(bytes)
  (bytes.to_f/1.megabyte).round(2)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of your JavaScript function would be

```
def bytes_to_megabytes (bytes)
    (bytes.to_f / 1024 / 1024 * 100).round / 100.0
end
```

Ruby does integer division whereas JavaScript does floating-point division. Thus you have to make sure that at least one operand is a floating-point number.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it in Rails application, you can use unbuilt method "number_to_human_size".

refer url for more details: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_human_size

1. number_to_human_size(483989, precision: 2)                         # => 470 KB
2. number_to_human_size(1234567, precision: 2, separator: ',')        # => 1,2 MB
3. number_to_human_size(1234567890123, precision: 5)                  # => "1.1228 TB"

Answer (score 0):

In ruby if u have MB/KB/Bytes and wants to convert into a base unit, bytes then use below function,

```
def convert_size_to_bytes(size)
  size_value, size_unit = size.split(" ")
  bytes = size_value.to_i

  case size_unit
  when "KB"
    bytes *= 1024
  when "MB"
    bytes *= 1024 * 1024
  when "GB"
    bytes *= 1024 * 1024 * 1024
  end

  bytes
end
```

And now u can pass `convert_size_to_bytes("30 MB")`, `convert_size_to_bytes("2000 KB")`
This will help u for calculation